# Get card data and pass to intent when clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-viewholder

I'm working with `CardView` and got stuck in a little problem. I have a `RecyclerView` where i am displaying some cards.

The problem is how to pass a card variable to another `activity` when it is clicked?

I Have the following View Holder:

```
public class DisciplinaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

protected TextView disciplinaNome;
protected TextView disciplinaCodigo;
protected TextView disciplinaCriador;
protected TextView disciplinaProfessor;
protected TextView disciplinaPeriodo;
protected CardView card;
protected ImageButton calendarButton;

public DisciplinaViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    disciplinaNome = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nome);
    disciplinaCodigo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.codigo);
    disciplinaCriador = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.criadaPor);
    disciplinaProfessor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.professor);
    disciplinaPeriodo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.periodo);


    calendarButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.calendarBuutton);
    calendarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), CalendarActivity.class);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    card = (CardView) itemView;
  }
}
```

An example would be: Supposing I have 3 cards:

```
>Card1(name = "First Card"), 
>Card2(name = "Second Card"),
>Card3(name = "Third Card").
```

When I press a `button` inside one of these cards, I want to get the name variable from the pressed card and pass it inside a `intent` on the `onClick()` method. So, if I press the `button` inside Card1, I would pass the value "First Card" to my next `activity`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you set list of your RecyclerView?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get what you are asking. You want to know how I pass the information that will be displayed on the cards?

Comment: you can pass  serialize object like "list.get(position)" on click of cardview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use extras for that :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), CalendarActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("extraName", extraValue);
```

please notice you will get issues launching the good activity with your method.
Since RecyclerViews recycle list items, you need to set the click listener in the `onBindViewHolder` method and not in the ViewHolder constructor.

Comment: Thank You very much! Both your code and your tip about using onBindViewHolder got my application running really smoth.

Answer (score 1):

For accessing TextView from Button Click use `v.getParent` to access View's from layout as:

```
        ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup)v.getParent();
        TextView disciplinaNome =(TextView)parentView.findViewById(R.id.nome);
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), CalendarActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", disciplinaNome.getText().toString());
        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Or you can also use `getTag/setTag` to access name value according to card click.

Answer (score 0):

try adding intent in onBindViewHolder

```
  view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),                       
            MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("onClick",viewHolder.getAdapterPosition);
            Log.i("CustomAdapter",viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()+"");
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```